# Temporal Logic of Actions: always and eventually definitions?

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic

I am familiarizing myself with the TLA. On the [7th page](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/lamport-actions.pdf) following definition of the "always" (also pronounced as "box") is given:
[image: Always]
Right after the formal definition, informal explanation in plain English says following:
[image: Always informally]

I am bothered with sentence:

> The formula $<s_0, ...>[|F|]$ asserts that $F$ is true at time $0$ of this behavior, and $<s_n, ...>[|F|]$ asserts that it is true at time $n$.

According to the definition [|F|] deals with **subbehaviors**. That's what $\forall n \in \mathbb{Nat}: <s_n, s_{n+1}, s_{n+2}, ...>$ stands for - it defines the **subbehavior** of the original **behavior** $<s_0, s_1, s_2, ..., s_{n}, ...>$. According to my understanding, **it does not** deal with exact state $s_n$ at the moment $n$; hence, to my understanding, informal English description is not quite correct and it should have been phrased in the different way:

> The formula $<s_0, s_1, s_2, ...>[|F|]$ asserts that $F$ is true *starting from the state at time 0 and infinetely long onward*, and $<s_n, s_{n+1}, s_{n+2}, ...>[|F|]$ asserts that it is true *starting from the state at the time $n$ and infinetely long onward*.

Am I right? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It seems only a notational issue; see [CTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic#Semantics_of_CTL): basically, the meaning is "from now (the current state) on".

Comment: It looks like the semantics they give for $\langle s_n, s_{n+1}, \ldots\rangle [F]$ is actually what they explain, according to which $F$ is true at time $n$ (but maybe false in the future). I think their semantics makes sense for the following subsection (3.2) and for definition (9) at the top of page 9. I haven't thoroughly read the paper, though.

Comment: @frabala "moment-wise" semantics indeed makes sense for the TLA+ toolset; since the article is written by the TLA+ inventor and aims software engineers rather then matematicians.. I guess that's why plain English explanation slightly disagrees with formal one.

Comment: I don't see where the formal specs disagree with the text. The "moment-wise" semantics of a box-formula is the "moment-wise" semantics of the unboxing of that formula, *but for all $n$ greater than that moment*. The correction you suggest for the text would be correct if you replaced "$[F]$" with "$[\square F]$". That's what I understand from what I read.

Comment: The semantics they use is generally "moment-wise". But in a sense, the box operator makes the "moment-wise" semantics of a formula future-proof.